# Call external OSGI bundle from EAR package

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, osgi, ear

I follow this tutorial http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-osgiservice-cdi.html
  I'm interested is it possible to replace the simple web client (WAR) package who calls the OSGI bundles with the EAR package. I want to create a EAR package which can call services from external OSGI bundle.

kind regards
Peter

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I will answer myself:
 Yes you can! Create a managed bean into the EAR file and implement a java interface in the OSGI bundle. Be careful about the dependencies.